# Короткая обработка обращения к значению несуществующего ключа массива? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Пытаемся получить значение из json массива по ключу. Если ключа такого нет, то присваиваем значение по умолчанию. Как правильно и максимально коротко написать? Так правильно?

```
let res = arr.key || 0;
```

Comment: Где пример кода с *получить значение из json массива по ключу*?

Comment: Используйте ternary для этого

Comment: Степан, разве arr.key не пример кода? Вот например json
let arr = ('key': 1, 'key2': 2);
arr.key1 содержит значение 1.
arr.key3 ничего не содержит.
отсюда и вопрос как обойти исключение подставив например 0
массив парсится из внешнего сервера, может быть не полный.

Comment: @GreenX5 Замечание Степана справедливо, потому что в JS массивами считаются только объекты с цифровыми индексами, доступ к которым через квадратные скобки, а не по ключу. А то, что в других языках называется "ассоциативные массивы", в JS - это объекты. То есть `let obj = {'key': 1, 'key2': 2};`, а не arr.

Comment: Павел, еще раз спасибо, да, есть пока пробел с объектно - ориентированным JS  после python  и lua, буду вникать ). Круглые скобки конечно была описка.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть препроцессор или не старый браузер, то можно использовать [Оператор нулевого слияния](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

`let res = arr.key ?? 0;`

Он, в отличие от оператора `||` срабатывает только если левая часть `null` или `undefined`, а не любое ложное значение типа нуля или пустой строки.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё автор уточнил, динамический ли ключ. Вдруг там arr[key] нужно.

Comment: Павел, спасибо, исчерпывающе. Оба варианта пригодятся.